# App Not Installed error while installing release build

Tags: android, apk, release, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.3

I am getting this error since I update Android Studio and due to that changed app gradle. And this issue is for marshmallow devices only. App is getting installed on sansung s7 with nougat.

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
         signingConfigs {
          config {
            keyAlias '#########'
            keyPassword '########'
            storeFile file('#########')
            storePassword '############'
         }
     }
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
      defaultConfig {
        applicationId "###########"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 14
        versionName '14.0'
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
     }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
        preDexLibraries = fal  se             
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-
           android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
    packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
      exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
   android {
      lintOptions {
          disable 'MissingTranslation'
          disable 'ResourceName'
      }
    } 
}
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
}
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':croplibrary')
compile project(path: ':ucrop')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

}

I face this issue after android studio update since morning.And it is having issue with release APK only, If I install debug APK directly from Studio it is working well.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error I am getting is 'App Not installed.' for release APK only. I am installing it from phone itself.

Comment: Did you change the certificate for signing the apk?

Comment: Can you cut `signingConfig signingConfigs.config` this line and paste  inside `release` tag. Currently you don't have signconfig for release version.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. It is resolved. It was due to Android Studio version 2.3.2., in this version while building signed apk I was checking only 'Full APK Signature' then also checked 'Jar Signature' and issue resolved.